# Read XML from file with utf-8

Tags: java, xml, spring, utf-8, anypoint-studio

I have a mule flow with a spring bean that reads a static XML file encoded in utf-8. However it messes up all the non-english characters.
The bean is defined as follows:

```
     <spring:bean id="LoadFile" name="Bean" class="java.lang.String">
    <spring:constructor-arg>
       <spring:bean id="Test" name="org.springframework.util.FileCopyUtils" class="org.springframework.util.FileCopyUtils" factory-method="copyToByteArray">
            <spring:constructor-arg type="java.io.InputStream" value="classpath:Settings.xml"/>
        </spring:bean> 
    </spring:constructor-arg>
</spring:bean> 
    </spring:beans>
```

If I read the same file using my own code like :

```
        InputStream in = this.getClass().getClassLoader()
            .getResourceAsStream(name);
```

It's utf-8 and works. How can I define the springbean to care about encodings?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are creating a `String` by calling its constructor that takes a `byte[]`, which will interpret the bytes using the default character encoding of your system, which is probably not UTF-8.

Specify the character encoding, by using the right constructor of `String`. This should work (I haven't tested it):

```
<spring:bean id="LoadFile" name="Bean" class="java.lang.String">
    <spring:constructor-arg>
        <spring:bean id="Test" name="org.springframework.util.FileCopyUtils" class="org.springframework.util.FileCopyUtils" factory-method="copyToByteArray">
            <spring:constructor-arg type="java.io.InputStream" value="classpath:Settings.xml"/>
        </spring:bean> 
    </spring:constructor-arg>
    <spring:constructor-arg value="UTF-8"/>
</spring:bean>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the nice explanation, it worked!

Answer (score 1):

Add UTF-8 charset constructor arg for String bean

```
<spring:bean id="LoadFile" name="Bean" class="java.lang.String">
    <spring:constructor-arg index="0">
       <spring:bean id="Test" name="org.springframework.util.FileCopyUtils" class="org.springframework.util.FileCopyUtils" factory-method="copyToByteArray">
            <spring:constructor-arg type="java.io.InputStream" value="classpath:Settings.xml"/>
        </spring:bean> 
    </spring:constructor-arg>

    <spring:constructor-arg index="1" value="UTF-8">
 </spring:bean>
```

Java equivalent

```
new String(byte_array, "UTF-8")
```